# Everything expands to screenwidth inside a Listview. Can I change that?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a design of a chat screen for an app that I'm making.
To make it scrollable I placed all the chat messages inside a listview. But everything I place inside a list view expands horizontally to match screenwidth (Width that the Listview widget has). Can I turn this off so I can line out my chat messages to one side and the other chat message to the other side like in whatsapp? Anything other than a ListView solution is also alright as long as I can scroll

[image]

This is how it looks now.

[image]

This is the code of my current page. I really hope someone can help me with this issue.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import '../../Library/Library.dart';
//import '../../Ui/ChatMessage.dart';

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return new ChatScreenState();
    }
}

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {

    bool overlayShouldBeVisible = false;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
                new Scaffold(
                    appBar: new AppBar(
                        title: new Text(
                            'Chatroom name',
                            style: new TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                        ),
                        centerTitle: true,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                        elevation: 0.0,
                    ),
                    body: new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                            new Expanded(
                                child: new Container(
                                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                        //image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage('assets/backgroundChat.jpg',),fit: BoxFit.cover)
                                    ),
                                    child: new ListView(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                            new Text('Test'),
                                            new Card(
                                                color: Colors.green,
                                                child: new Padding(
                                                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                                    child: new Column(
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                            new Text('Message'),
                                                            new Text('17:00'),
                                                        ],
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                            new Card(
                                                color: Colors.green,
                                                child: new Padding(
                                                    padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                                                    child: new Column(
                                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                                                        children: <Widget>[
                                                            new Text('Message'),
                                                            new Text('17:00'),
                                                        ],
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                            ),
                                        ],
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                            new Container(
                                height: 50.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                child: new Row(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                        new Expanded(
                                            child: new Padding(
                                                padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                                                child: new TextField(),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                        new Material(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            child: new InkWell(
                                                child: new Padding(
                                                    padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                                                    child: new Icon(
                                                        Icons.send,
                                                        color: Colors.blue,
                                                    ),
                                                ),
                                                onTap: () => print('send'),
                                            ),
                                        ),
                                    ],
                                ),
                            ),
                        ],
                    ),
                ),
                //overlayShouldBeVisible == true ? new JsonLoader(): new Container(),
                //Library.debugMode ? new DebugOverlay(): new Container(),
            ],
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I want the Listview to take all the available (Vertical) space. Is there another way than using a expanded to do that ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Okay! Thank you :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have done a little bit of refactor on your code an here is the result:

**Basically I keep a flag for the type of message (sent or received) and align the message card accordingly**

**Note I did not have the time to review the code but I noticed a lot of unnecessary nesting so you may want to revise the layout a little bit**

[image]

```
class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new ChatScreenState();
  }
}

class ChatMessage extends StatelessWidget {
  String type;
  ChatMessage({this.type});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Row(
      mainAxisAlignment:
          this.type == "sent" ? MainAxisAlignment.end : MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Card(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: new Padding(
            padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
            child: new Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                new Text('Message'),
                new Text('17:00'),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  bool overlayShouldBeVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text(
              'Chatroom name',
              style: new TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0.0,
          ),
          body: new Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Expanded(
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      //image: new DecorationImage(image: new AssetImage('assets/backgroundChat.jpg',),fit: BoxFit.cover)
                      ),
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new ChatMessage(
                        type: "sent",
                      ),
                      new ChatMessage(
                        type: "sent",
                      ),
                      new ChatMessage(
                        type: "received",
                      ),
                      new ChatMessage(
                        type: "sent",
                      ),
                      new ChatMessage(
                        type: "received",
                      ),
                      new ChatMessage(
                        type: "received",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Container(
                height: 50.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                child: new Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Expanded(
                      child: new Padding(
                        padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
                        child: new TextField(),
                      ),
                    ),
                    new Material(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: new InkWell(
                        child: new Padding(
                          padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
                          child: new Icon(
                            Icons.send,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () => print('send'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        //overlayShouldBeVisible == true ? new JsonLoader(): new Container(),
        //Library.debugMode ? new DebugOverlay(): new Container(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

or as Rémi suggested you can just use `Align` instead of `Row` like so:

```
return new Align(
      alignment:this.type!="sent"?  FractionalOffset.centerLeft:FractionalOffset.centerRight,
                  child: 
                    new Card(
    ..
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. Let me check it out right now!

Comment: `Align` is a much more straighforward solution

Comment: Looking at the code there is not much that is changed in structure. What part of it made the messages not take the entire screenwidth? Just for my knowledge so I know how to work in the future. But it works amazing. Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh I think I see it. Is it because you placed the cards in a Row?

Comment: @KevinWalter it was because of a Row yes, you may actually want to check @Rémi comment, I honestly did not think of `Align` but yes it seems like a better solution here.

Comment: Yeah I've already implemented Align. It works really great! Again, thank you!

Answer (score 58):

You can use [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget to align it's child inside it's parent.

Simply wrap your list nodes (Card instances) inside a `Align`.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
//import '../../Library/Library.dart';
//import '../../Ui/ChatMessage.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: new ChatScreen(),
    ),
  );
}

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new ChatScreenState();
  }
}

class ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  bool overlayShouldBeVisible = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(body: new ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return new Align(
          alignment: index.isEven ? Alignment.centerLeft : Alignment.centerRight,
          child: new Card(
            child: new Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: new Text("Hello World $index"),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Also a really good solution! Looks like it all comes down to placing the card inside a Align or a Row to stop it being 100% in width! Thank you!

Comment: Row is a bad idea. Align is for single-child alignment. Row is for multiple children :)

Comment: You just need to wrap the child widget you wish  not to  take up whole screen's width with Wrap() widget.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late but this may be the easiest solution. I don't know if this is a good practice or not (you may comment below if it is not).

What I did is I wrapped the message (I mean the widget that contains the message) into a row and added a `Spacer()` widget at first or in last depending upon whether the message is on right side or on left

So the code might look something like (The code below is for message on the left side)

```
Row(
children: [
  Card(
    color: Colors.green,
    child: new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text('Message'),
          new Text('17:00'),
        ],
      ),
    ), 
  )
  Spacer(),
]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers.  This one helped me a bit more:

[flutter ListView children size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54412279/flutter-listview-children-size)

I ended up with code like this:

```
  var sizeW = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  var leftCut = 0.0;
  var rightCut = 0.0;
  if (sizeW > WEB_MAX_WIDTH) {
    leftCut = (sizeW - WEB_MAX_WIDTH) / 2;
    rightCut = leftCut;
  }
```

And then use those like this:

```
          return Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right:rightCut, left: leftCut),
              padding:
                  EdgeInsets.only(left: (_fullList[index].level * 30.0)),
              child: Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                ...
```