# Flutter : Can't get correct size of Card that contain row

Tags: flutter

I created a card and set  a width of container to 300 but i get the card with a width more than 300

```
return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:5,vertical: 10),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                      CourseInfoPage(widget.courseId)));
        },
        child: Container(
          width: 300,
          height: 200,
          color:Colors.yellow,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              // courseText(context, course, 180),
              // courseImage(course, 150),
              Container(width: 100,color:Colors.red),
              Container(width:200,color: Colors.green,)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

and when i get it inside ListView like this

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
        child: Selector<CategoriesModel, List<CourseModel>>(
          selector: (buildContext, model) => model.getCoursesByCategory(categoryName),
          builder: (context, value, child) => value == null
              ? CircularProgressIndicator()
              : ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  itemCount: value.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return CourseCard(value[index].courseId);
                  },
                ),
        ),
      ),
```

I want the card to be exactly 300 and one container to 100 and an other to 200 which make it to be 300 but as you can see in the below screenshot i get this extra yellow space

[image]

Comment: I don't know flutter, but maybe you can try to set the width as a percentage of the parent? 33% and 67% respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is in the **Listview** widget. Listview expands its children. To prevent this from happening, you need to wrap your ***CourseCard*** inside an Align widget and give it an alignment. check the following code. also, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49820932/9689717) answer for more information.

```
ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: CourseCard(value[index].courseId),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Thank you very much it solved my problem ,  i couldn't find that in documentation